# How to update one table from two different pages in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have one table name files
Now I have two types of files, one file purchase and second file sale but I use only one table.
I am using laravel resource controller

my table files 
First i insert filepurchase data and store filesale value null
[![enter image description here]

```
   public function store(Request $request, File $file)
    {
    $file->p_name                  = $request->p_name;
    $file->p_co                    = $request->p_co;
    $file->type_of_file            = $request->type_of_file;
    $file->file_status             = $request->file_status;
    $file->save();

    // $arr['file']=File::all();
    // $p=$file->p_price;
    $data = [
            $file->id,
            $file->p_price,
        ];

    return view('filetransaction.create',compact('data'));
  }
```

This is working fine.I want that when i click on sale button i insert file sale record against filepurchase with same id, and update null fields
[![enter image description here]

Comment: You just want to update already existing record?

Comment: yes but different fields in same table

Comment: Then you can do that simply do that using record id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways to complete that task , you only need record id e.g.:

```
 $table = Table::where('id', $id)->first();
 //Update record details
  $table->save();
```

OR

```
 Table::where('id', $id)->update([ 'index' => 'value' ]);   //need update details array
```

OR

```
 $table= Table::firstOrCreate(['id' => $id]);
```

OR

```
// Retrieve the Table the attributes, or instantiate a new instance...
 $table= Table::firstOrNew(['id' => $id]);
```

OR

```
 $table = Table::find($id);
```

then

```
 $table->save();
```

Hope this helps.